# Getting InvalidGeometry: LinearRing failed ring test after upgrading rgeo gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgis, geos, rgeo

After upgrading the [rgeo](https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo) gem from 0.6.0 to 2.1.1, we've started to get 'LinearRing failed ring test' on certain geometries that never caused us problems before. (The geometry data is generated from external sources outside of our control, and stored in PostGIS table.)

**rgeo initializer:**

```
GEO_FACTORY = RGeo::Geographic.simple_mercator_factory
PROJECTION_FACTORY = GEO_FACTORY.projection_factory
RGeo::ActiveRecord::SpatialFactoryStore.instance.tap do |config|
  config.default = PROJECTION_FACTORY
end
```

**Example code:**

```
district = District.first
# Convert projected geometry to geographic geometry
geographic_geometry = GEO_FACTORY.unproject(district.geometry)
```

> RGeo::Error::InvalidGeometry: LinearRing failed ring test

I also tried initializing the factory with the following options, but the errors persisted:

```
FACTORY = RGeo::Geographic.simple_mercator_factory(uses_lenient_assertions:true)
FACTORY = RGeo::Geographic.simple_mercator_factory(lenient_multi_polygon_assertions:true)
```

I've inspected some of these geometries where that are failing the LinearRing test, and it appears they are failing for a variety of reasons. Some possibly violate [ring winding order](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.1.6), while with others I couldn't perceive the exact problem. But the point is, these are all geometries that we were able to work with before, and now are raising errors. I'd like to understand how we can return to the more lenient mode.

**NOTES:**

- This is only happening on my Macbook (GEOS version 3.8.0), but not on our Linux production server (GEOS version 3.5.0)

**REFERENCES:**

- https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo/issues/194
- https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo-geojson/issues/33

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be an issue with the `rgeo` gem but rather the underlying `geos` library on your mac.

There appears to be a difference in the way that `geos` `3.8.x` (`3.8.1` is the latest version in Homebrew circa 4/13/2020) and earlier versions of the `geos` library handle the `is_simple` calculation that determines Polygon validity. This affects any `RGeo` factory (most of them but not `RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory` or `RGeo::Cartesian.simple_factory`) backed by the CAPI.

If you download version `3.5.x` of geos from https://trac.osgeo.org/geos/ and build it with cmake (takes a while but installs cleanly) you should have consistent behavior between your production and local development environments.

If you were using the `simple_mercator` factory I doubt that differences in how spherical coordinates (implemented in pure ruby) are validated explain the differences in behavior that you see.

See this issue: https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo/issues/218

Comment: I think you're right, big thanks for this! I was ready to let the issue slide as I figured it wouldn't affect production, but now I know I'm going to have to prepare some sort of workaround. Will post further thoughts at https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo/issues/218

Answer (score 2):

You most probably encountered this [1] bug. Reproducing needs Mac OS and shows the error you have:

```
  RGeo::Error::InvalidGeometry (LinearRing failed ring test)
```

Issue is linked to pull request [2], which found the issue on Float vs BigDecimal difference. Somehow Floats are not so precise, when there are enough decimals included.

***Side note:*** Pull request is only 26 days old, so it is still open, thus you'll need to build it from branch for the moment.

---

**Source:**

[1] https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo/issues/212

[2] https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo/pull/213

Comment: I'm not certain the cross platform bug is accounted for by the floating point issue (I've ran into that too). The following throws exceptions on both osx and linux:
```RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory.parse_wkt('POLYGON((-93.572755591195 44.615834475162, -93.571098455347 44.613948476312, -93.571098455347 44.613948476313, -93.571098455347 44.613948476314, -93.571325365812 44.615739119667, -93.572627021193 44.613957229694, -93.572755591195 44.615834475162))')
```
but the other factories (RGeo::Geographic.simple_mercator_factory) diverge. They throw exceptions on osx and not on Linux.

Comment: My comment above the differences between mac and linux are incorrect. The difference is between version `3.8.x` vs older versions of geos. It seems like a cross platform issue because homebrew updates versions ahead of most linux distros but once 3.8 drops in linux distros (ie `focal` for Ubuntu) the same issue will be visible there.